# How to get back the welcome page back in Visual studio code with nrf connect extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nrf-connect

[image]

I am using nrf connect and VSCode together and it was fine until 6 months and now I cannot recollect what broke the welcome page. Can you guide me on how to fix this?

Tools used:

nRF Connect for Desktop
nRF Command Line Tools
Visual Studio Code

I would be really appreciative of any valuable insights.

[image: Welcome page missing Normal wayIssue for nrf connect extension]

Comment: what's your startup editor setting set to?

Comment: @starball hey how can I check that? did you mean the settings.json file?   That files have the following content                  
  {
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "nrf-connect.welcome.showOnStartup": true,
    "nrf-connect.toolchain.path": "${nrf-connect.toolchain:2.3.0}",
    "nrf-connect.topdir": "c:\\ncs\\v2.3.0",
    "nrf-connect.enableTelemetry": true,
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never"

Comment: @starball I found what you were saying and the startup editor is set to welcome page though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The welcome view was removed in a recent nRF Connect for VS Code update. See https://nrfconnect.github.io/vscode-nrf-connect/release_notes/connect/2023.9.169.html#welcome-view